# static functions using generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface, casting

I was looking at the source code of Predicate in java.util.function, (which for context, is a functional interface that returns a boolean value having taken some generic input of type T) when I came across the following functions:

```
    static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
        return (null == targetRef)
                ? Objects::isNull
                : object -> targetRef.equals(object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<? super T> target) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(target);
        return (Predicate<T>)target.negate();
    }
```

and I am puzzled by how static functions can be used with all these generic types lying around. What's going on?

I was expecting some type inference makes this happen. In the first method, the return function is a function that can be fed into `Predicate<T>` implicitly, but since the `targetRef` argument is of type `Object`, I would expect that this can only be made into a class of type `Predicate<Object>`, which seems to me, defeats the point of using `T` at all in the function.

The second function, I cannot even think of a reasonable inference pattern, it seems absurd. The return type is cast into `Predicate<T>`, but `target.negate` will return `Predicate<? super T>`, which makes taking a super argument itself strange, and further, because of the typecast in the return statement, and the obscurity in the argument as well, it is not possible to know a sensible `T` from either. How do either of these methods work, and why were they defined that way?

Comment: A generic method is a method which declares at least one type parameter. The *caller* decides which actual type argument(s) to use for the type parameter(s). Your phrase “that this can only be made into a class of type Predicate” is incomprehensible. You should mark code fragments with back-ticks, so that type arguments are not confused for HTML tags. As said, the *caller* decides what `T` is, hence, returning a `Predicate<T>` allows the caller to decide what actual parameterization the predicate will have. Which works, because every object has an `equals` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can always specify the types explicitly:

```
static <T> Predicate<T> isEqual(Object targetRef) {
    return (null == targetRef)
            ? Objects::isNull
            : (T object) -> targetRef.equals(object);
}
```

So while `targetRef` is of type `Object`, `object` is of type `T`.

`T` depends on the calling context, e.g.:

```
Predicate.isEqual(something); // T == Object
Predicate.<String>isEqual(something); // T == String
Predicate<Double> p = Predicate.isEqual(something); // T == Double
Stream.of(1,2,3).filter(Predicate.isEqual(2)); // T == Integer
```

Comment: Right, but since it's a static method, it would be invoked like Predicate.isEqual(myobject), where for the sake of argument, myobject is an Integer. In that case, what is T?

Comment: @SoullessWarrior that depends on the calling context. `Predicate<String> p = Predicate.isEqual(myInteger);`

Comment: Ah, thanks! That clarifies everything. The only question that remains is: Why does the second method take a superclass and then cast the negation down into T?

Comment: @SoullessWarrior the result of invoking a generic method is a _polyexpression_: the same code can have different types, depending on how it is used (e.g. the type of variable it is assigned to).

Comment: @SoullessWarrior the cast is narrowing the permissible argument types from "something, we don't know exactly what, but `T` is acceptable" to "only `T` is acceptable". Provided the API you're using has used generics appropriately, it should be able to accept predicates which are more general than needed; but sometimes, they don't accept general parameters, and you need e.g. an actual `Predicate<String>` instead of a `Predicate<Object>` to which you will only pass `String`s.

Answer (score 0):

For the first function, the `equals` method always takes an `Object`. You might expect `Object::equals` to take only a parameter of its own type, but that's not what it does. That leaves the `<T>` parameter to be inferred purely by what the caller needs: You can easily pass `isEqual("")` to something that expects a `Predicate<Integer>`, and that'll work fine (and always returns `false`).

The `<T>` for the second function is inferred from the caller in much the same way. The `super` just means "any `Predicate` that can *consume* a `T`". The cast is needed because the compiler can't know that the `Predicate` returned by `negate` is always safe as a `Predicate<T>`.